# php read from textarea each line doesn't work why?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a code read from textarea each line in Array like print $line[1] ;
print $line[2] ;

I replaced print with echo but syill doesn't work

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="textareaname">
Line one test
Line 2 test
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$text =  = trim($_POST['textareaname']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    // processing here
} 
print $line[1] ;
print $line[2] ;
?>
```

HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: the 500 is from `$text =  = `, the `\n` issue is something else, if you want `\n` into html `<br>`'s, use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or use `white-space:pre-wrap` css prop

Comment: Thank you but the output is inininin

Comment: I put one
two
three
four in text area and the output was newohrouf

Comment: Can you update your question with your expected output

Comment: Look at your HTML source; the line breaks are in there alright. You need to use what @Lawrence mentioned about the `<br>` tags.

Comment: it will output `in` as `i` is second char, `n` is third in `$line` after trim of `Line one test`. Need to show expected output, as code is doing what its told.

Comment: All what i'm trying to do is make the code take each line form TextArea and read it as a string to create php bulk mailer :(

Comment: Can you please fix the code and make it read each line from the textarea as a string ? :(

Comment: You got it you just need to move the printing into the loop: https://3v4l.org/PoeEF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line` is variable that holds the last element (and it is **string**) of `$textAr` after the `foreach` loop is over. And using `$line[1]` prints **second symbol of the string**.

What you really want to print and see is `$textAr[0]` or `$textAr[1]`:

```
print $textArr[1];
```

This will print required element of your `$textArr` array.

**Update**: if you need to send email assuming that each line is valid address you can use this code:

```
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    echo 'Current email is ' . $line;
    // sending email code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked , but what $line was for? I got the code from here so $line is unknown string , i use it to create bulk mail sender how to make it take alines without i put textAr[1] Textar[2] etc i need it take the whole array and send to each line

Comment: `$line` is used in your `foreach ($textAr as __$line__)`. On each iteration of the loop `$line` stores the current iterated value from array.

Comment: Not me they even down my question i clicked correct answer you gave me perfect answer i don't understand why they downvote your answer and my question , Do you know how to make it take each one from the code as a string without type textAr[]1 , 2 , 3 etc :(